# I want istio envoy proxy to translate http traffic to https

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm using k8s with istio.
And, I have external api with https endpoint (mutual tls)

And I don't want every api request from k8s pod to implement mutual tls call, so it would be great if istio envoy proxy can process mutual tls. Then pod can call api with http, and request would be converted to https mtls request by envoy.

```
+---------------------------------+
| (pod) ---http--> (envoy proxy) -|-https(mtls)--> external api
+---------------------------------+
```

I managed to find a solution of mutual tls with envoy.
[How can I use custom client certificate for external service with istio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343583/how-can-i-use-custom-client-certificate-for-external-service-with-istio)

Now I should find how to setup envoy proxy to convert http to https.
I guess that I should use **ServiceEntry**, **DestinationRule**, **VirtualService**, but I stuck here.

Help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway-tls-origination/#perform-mutual-tls-origination-with-an-egress-gateway) is a task on istio.io how to do it.