# Istio: Unable to mount secrets to the pod

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-sidecar, istio-gateway

I'm a noob with Istio and K8s so sorry if this question sounds a little dumb.

I'm trying to provide my own certs to the Gateway deployment for which I created secrets like below.

```
$ kubectl create -n istio-system secret tls certs --key example.comkey.pem --cert example.com.pem
$ kubectl create -n istio-system secret generic ca-certs --from-file=rootCA.pem
```

Edited my deployment

```
sidecar.istio.io/userVolumeMount: '[{"name":"certs", "mountPath":"/etc/certs", "readonly":true},{"name":"ca-certs", "mountPath":"/etc/ca-certs", "readonly":true}]'
sidecar.istio.io/userVolume: '[{"name":"certs", "secret":{"secretName":"certs"}},{"name":"ca-certs", "secret":{"secretName":"ca-certs"}}]'
```

Followed the steps provided in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57347134/1529274) and [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway-tls-origination/#redeploy-the-egress-gateway-with-the-client-certificates) but I still do not see the files mounted.

Am I missing something?

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.2", GitCommit:"092fbfbf53427de67cac1e9fa54aaa09a28371d7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-16T12:59:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.2", GitCommit:"092fbfbf53427de67cac1e9fa54aaa09a28371d7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-16T12:53:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: related link from a non-answer posted as an answer: https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/44946

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue. I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it though.
I missed adding `volumeMounts` and `volumes`. Once I made the below change, I could see my files mounted.

```
volumeMounts:
- name: certs
  mountPath: /etc/certs
  readOnly: true
- name: ca-certs
  mountPath: /etc/ca-certs
  readOnly: true

volumes:
- name: certs
  secret:
  secretName: certs
  optional: true
- name: ca-certs
  secret:
  secretName: ca-certs
  optional: true
```